# Dependencies validation using Cerberus

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

Am validating a CSV file with [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/index.html) but am struggling with what I'd assume is some basic logic

**Scenario:**

A CSV file has 2 columns. `Column 2` requires to have a value only if `Column 1` has a value. If `Column 1` is empty then `Column 2` should also be empty.

Am thinking this would be one of the most straight forward rules to write but so far nothing is working as expected.

Below is the same logic using python dictionaries.

```
from cerberus import Validator
v = Validator()

schema = {
    "col1": {"required": False},
    "col2": {"required": True, "dependencies": "col1"},
}

document = {
    "col1": "a",
    "col2": ""
}

v.validate(document, schema)  # This responds with True!? Why?
v.errors
{}
```

I would have expected an error for `Column 2` here because `Column 1` has been provided but here the result is `True` meaning no error

I've checked raised [issues on github](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/issues) but can't seem to find any obvious solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note** 
> The evaluation of this rule (`dependencies`) does **not** consider any constraints defined with the `required` rule.

Whatever the `"required"` would be:

```
from cerberus import Validator
v = Validator()

document = {
    "col1": "a",
    "col2": ""
}

schema = {
    "col1": {"required": False},
    "col2": {"required": True, "dependencies": "col1"},
}

print(v.validate(document, schema))  # True
print(v.errors) # {}
```

---

```
schema = {
    "col1": {"required": True},
    "col2": {"required": True, "dependencies": "col1"},
}


print(v.validate(document, schema))  # True
print(v.errors)  # {}
```

---

```
schema = {
    "col1": {"required": True},
    "col2": {"required": False, "dependencies": "col1"},
}


print(v.validate(document, schema))  # True
print(v.errors)  # {}
```

http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#dependencies

---

**Update**:

Solution for your condition "*Make col2 mandatory if col1 has a value in it.*".

To apply a sophisticated rules - create a custom *Validator* as shown below:

```
from cerberus import Validator


class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_depends_on_col1(self, depends_on_col1, field, value):
        """ Test if a field value is set depending on `col1` field value.
        """
        if depends_on_col1 and self.document.get('col1', None) and not value:
            self._error(field, f"`{field}` cannot be empty given that `col1` has a value")


v = MyValidator()

schema = {
    "col1": {"required": False},
    "col2": {"required": True, "depends_on_col1": True},
}

print(v.validate({"col1": "a", "col2": ""}, schema))  # False
print(v.errors) # {'col2': ['`col2` cannot be empty given that `col1` has a value']}

print(v.validate({"col1": "", "col2": ""}, schema))  # True
print(v.errors) # {}

print(v.validate({"col1": 0, "col2": "aaa"}, schema))  # True
print(v.errors) # {}
```

Note, you need to run into convention of what column `col1` values should be treated as empty (to adjust a custom validator rules).

---

Extended version to specify a "dependancy" field name:

```
class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_depends_on_col(self, col_name, field, value):
        """ Test if a field value is set depending on `col_name` field value.
        """
        if col_name and self.document.get(col_name, None) and not value:
            self._error(field, f"`{field}` cannot be empty given that `{col_name}` has a value")


v = MyValidator()

document = {"col1": "a", "col2": ""}

schema = {
    "col1": {"required": False},
    "col2": {"required": True, "depends_on_col": "col1"},
}
```

http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/customize.html

Comment: Thanks for the guide but I still don't get it even after reading that `dependencies` section several times. Your examples seem to be saying that if the constraint `required` is present, then `dependencies` won't be evaluated. If that is what you mean and that is what that `dependencies` section means then its not working as I'd expect as I've tested the sample document above by removing the `required` constraint but still the sample code above does not fail.

Comment: *seem to be saying that if the constraint required is present, then dependencies won't be evaluated.* - not that, but opposite. That's how the documentation says.

Comment: Ok. Your statement above helped me reread the documentation with a different mindset. So the `dependencies` validation is about the field not the value of the field. So in my case, because the `col1` is present in the document, then `col2` won't fail. So do you know which validation rule I should use when I want the evaluation to be done against the value of `col1` instead of just the `field name`?

Comment: @lukik, describe the expected behaviour based on relationships between `col1` and `col2`

Comment: Make `col2` mandatory if `col1` has a value in it. The error would read something like *`col2` cannot be empty given that `col1` has a value*. Going with the examples in the original question, I would expect an error to be raised given that `col1's` value is `a` and `col2` does not have a value

Comment: @lukik, what a day! You got a solution, check my update.

Comment: @lukik, any concerns to provided solution?

Comment: Yap. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Quick one, how can I pass `col1` as a parameter instead of hardcoding it? Idea is so that I can reuse the function as several other columns have dependencies. Just to explain further. Am validating a `.csv` file with about 15 columns where `col2` depends on `col1`, `col6` depends on `col7` etc so I'd like to have a generic `depends_on_colX` that can be reused.

Comment: @lukik, see the extended version

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could do more than just mark your answer as the correct answer because this answer provides me with way better understanding of how Cerberus works than the docs have in the past few days of going through them. Be blessed. Get lucky.

Comment: @lukik, glad I was helpful for someone. Good luck

Comment: i'd recommend to use `check_with` instead of a custom rule. @lukik, pull request with documentation improvements are always welcome.

Comment: In my current scenario, am thinking the `custom rule` will work better than `check_with` because with `custom_rule` I am able to pass arguments in the schema allowing me more flexibility and reusability of the rule. `check_with` only takes the `field` and the `value` as arguments thus its a bit limiting.. But I stand corrected.  As for pull request on the documentation, I definitely will and will also try put together a guide based on my experience and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you transformed your csv input into a list of documents, you could first preprocess the documents in order to remove the `col2` field where it is empty:

```
for document in documents:
    if not document["col2"]:
        document.pop("col2")
```

Then this schema would do the job:

```
{"col1": {
    "oneof": [
        {"empty": True},
        {"empty": False, "dependencies": "col2"}
    ]
}}
```

Mind that the the `dependencies` and `required` rules don't consider the value of a field, but only the presence of the field in the document.