# How can one pass the same rule to a rules_set

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

Using [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/index.html), I've defined custom rules that validate data (CSV data) based on some parameters passed to the rule. See example rule below copied [from an answer in another question I'd asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56706472/1082673).

```
class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_custom_parameter_rule(self, rule_parameters, field, value):
        """ Test if a field value is set depending on `col_name` field value.
        """
        # Validate based on the rule parameters
        ...



v = MyValidator()

document = {"col1": "a", "col2": ""}

schema = {
    "field1": {"required": False},
    "field2": {"required": True, 
             "custom_parameter_rule": {"x": 1}, 
             "custom_parameter_rule": {"y": 2}"
            },  # Note that `custom_parameter_rule` is repeated which won't work
}
```

It so happens that in one field e.g. field2 above, a rule can be used several times but with different parameters. So in the example above, Field 1 could depend on Field 2 and again Field 1 could depend on Field 3. Meaning, I'd need to pass/run this rule twice.

Issue is that a `rules_set` only takes a `dict` which means the rule needs to be unique. So question is, how can I pass the same rule more than once.

I note the documentation states `A validation schema is a mapping, usually a dict.` so am wondering, can it be a list and if yes, how can I pass the rules as a list?

Comment: You could refactor the rule to deal with multiple parameters, couldn't you?

Comment: That phrase that you cite in the last paragraph refers to the possibility to use a string (as reference to a schema from a registry).